# Can not ping docker container in overlay network

Tags: docker, networking, overlay

I have 2 servers with docker installed.
I have successfully created a consul service.
I have create an overlay network with

```
docker network create -d overlay --subnet=172.27.31.0/24 --gateway=172.27.31.1 idmoverlay
```

I created a container with

```
docker run -d --ip=172.27.31.12 --network=idmoverlay --hostname=identityengine.skypro.ch --name=identityengine -v /etc/hosts:/etc/hosts -v /data/shared/docker/idm:/config -p 8028:8028 -p 524:524 -p 389:389 -p 8030:8030 -p 636:636 -e SILENT_INSTALL_FILE=/config/silent.properties --stop-timeout 100 identityengine:idm-4.8.4
```

I see in `docker network inspect idmoverlay` the container in the overlay network with ip address.

Nevertheless I can not ping the container from the docker host.

Comment: What should the application do when it receives the ICMP packet?  Is there any application code relevant to this question, or is it entirely about the Docker networking setup?

Comment: It is entirely about docker network setup. As you can see above, the container "identityengine" I created, should handle port 8028 624, 389, 8030 and 636. But none of these ports is reachable. So I tried to ping also without success. So i guess it's a general docker network connectivity problem.